# SQL Server - Mismatch in column datatype and tessellation scheme

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sqlgeography

I'm trying to create an index on my `Location` column in the DB.

Receiving this error: `Mismatch in column datatype and tessellation scheme`

It's a simple Geography computed field of a Latitude and Longitude field.

```
[Location]  AS ([geography]::Point([Latitude],[Longitude],(4326))) PERSISTED,
```

What am I doing wrong here?

In my app I'm filtering heavily on this `Location` column so I want to make sure it's indexed.

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Click the "Spatial" Column on the left and under the "General" section, where it says Tessellation Scheme, select "Geography Grid".  It is defaulted to Geometry which is causing the issue.

[image]

Comment: This should be accepted answer this did it for me, thanks Michael.

Comment: @Michael Bondi, I know it's been so long, but can you tell me if it runs for hours to create spatial index. My data set is about 30k rows and it's been running from 7 hours or so.

Comment: @Sree It didn't take that long for me but I only had a few thousand records or so - there are a lot of factors that could affect the time, like people querying the database which can cause locks, if other indexes exist on that table (clustered, etc), disk space, even the SQL edition (Standard vs Enterprise).  Unfortunately my knowledge of the inner workings of SQL server isn't that in depth to really provide a useful answer for you;  you might have to just wait it out.